# How to attack the integral $\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\left(e^x-1\right)^3}{1-\cos(x)\cos(2x)}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I've considered some integrals, some of the form $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\left(e^x-1\right)^3}{1-\cos(ax)\cos(bx)}dx.\tag{1}$$

I would like to know how to attack this kind of integrals. Can you help me about next integral? Is not required all details or a closed-form, only how start to work with the purpose to get the indefinite integral if you think that it is feasible, or well the definite integral, or justify a good approximation of it.

> **Question.** How to attack the integral $$\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\left(e^x-1\right)^3}{1-\cos(x)\cos(2x)}dx\,?$$ **Many thanks.**

Comment: Just kidding : I refuse to *attack* the monster !

Comment: Hi, cool integral ! Are you familiar with complex analysis and complex integration ?

Comment: Best day @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if it can be solved using residues @Rebellos

Comment: We meet again... note that it has residues every $2\pi$ for negative $x$. Also, the integrand looks somewhat like teeth: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/owplbxlnkm

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. Over the range of interest, the function is quite nice.

Comment: Just for the fun of it : a CAS computed the antiderivative of the monster.

Comment: The denominator can be expressed as $(1-\cos x)(2\cos^2x+2\cos x+1)$

Comment: @user243301 Sorry, was away from home. I'm pretty sure it can be soled using residues !

Comment: @Rebellos you have run when you heard that the integrand has teeth (... is a joke, see previous comment by SimpliFire). Thanks for contribtuions to you and the other users interested in the question,

Comment: Does anyone have an exact value of it?

Comment: @Shashi Yes, it's something like $0.37\dots$. Checked it earlier on WA.

Comment: [Here's a numerical value WA Link !](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+((e%5Ex-1)%5E3%2F(1-cos(x)*cos(2x)))+from+0+to+pi%2F4)

Comment: @Rebellos oh I meant in terms of numbers/functions like $\pi$, $\zeta(3)$ etc..

Comment: What about Taylor expansion?

Comment: I presume that for simple integrals (with that I was playing in Wolfram Alpha) lwith integrand like $\frac{x^3}{1-\cos^2(x)}$ works, since Wolfram Alpha calculated a closed-form of the indefinite integral. In y example I know that $\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)\cos(2x)}$ is a geometric, but in the denominator we've a power, thus it is difficult to me calculate the product. Many thanks @FDP